# Modificar posición sombra wordpress css

Tags: css, wordpress-theme

Estoy tratando de poner un bloque con sombra en la parte inferior de un POST de un BLOG, pero solo he conseguido esto:

[image: sombra arriba]

```
.content-area .format-gallery .post-thumbnail:before,
.content-area .format-image .post-thumbnail:before {
background: #000;
content: "";
display: block;
height: 75%;
left: 0;
opacity: 0.4;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: -1
```

}

este es el código que llevo, lo que necesito es que quede ubicado en la parte inferior... (algo como gravity bottom en xml)

Comment: Tienes `bottom:0` pero necesitas también poner `position:absolute` y que el elemento sobre el que quieres que se posicione tenga tambien algún valor en `position` que no sea `static`

Comment: puse position:absolute, y ya no se ve... ademas cambie top por bottom y tambien puse ambos y nada

Comment: como bien dicen @blonfu, el contenedor padre debe tener una posición, en este caso diría que `relative`, y en tu código poner posición `absolute` con `bottom: 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que poner el elemento en posición absoluta y luego darle un ancho también (yo he puesto `left:0` y `right:0` que viene a ser parecido a `width:100%`), sino no se verá. El elemento padre, en este caso `.fondo` tiene que tener posición también para que sirva de referencia:

```css
.fondo{
 background:url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-h-c-200-500-4.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
  width:200px;
  height:500px;
  color:white;
  position:relative;
 }

.fondo:before{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  height:75%;
  background:#000;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  opacity: 0.4;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fondo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus placeat alias aut sed, nihil ducimus sit. Saepe dolorum incidunt eligendi, accusamus repudiandae, harum a ipsam, hic fugiat quam quisquam et.</div>
```

Comment: gracias, lo implemente en mi caso y anduvo bien :)